# Clip Dataframe Arcgis for data driven map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, data-driven-pages, data-frame

I'm trying to do a map of several provinces bordering each other. The map needs to focus on each province and not the neighbors. therefore when using the data driven map function i would like to clip the dataframes extent to match the province in which is being exported...

obviously we can do them individually however one click functionality would be better.

Comment: Data driven pages designed for exactly same purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done.

See the Help on [Clip to current Data Driven Page extent](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/clipping-the-data-frame.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_03794949E01649E396EAAFA5DCEA000B):

> Data frame clipping can be used with Data Driven Pages. When Data
>   Driven Pages are enabled, you will see Clip to current data driven
>   page extent as one of the clip options. Selecting this option clips
>   the data frame with the shape of the index feature defining the extent
>   of the current Data Driven Page.

Comment: thanks very much, this did work. However now I find all my labels have become clipped as well. is there a way to give labels a priority over the data frame boundary to allow overlap?

Comment: these are labels associated with points.

Comment: I think that should be researched/asked as a separate question.